# What is the difference between scanf("%s", &str) and scanf("%s\n", &str)?

Tags: c, scanf

**Input**

There will be several lines in the input terminated with a line containing a single `*`. This last line
should not be processed. Each of the lines will contain either `Hajj` or `Umrah`.

**Output**

For each line of the input, output either `Hajj-e-Akbar` or `Hajj-e-Asghar` in separate lines without
quotations. For the exact format refer to the sample.

Here's my code for this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i = 1;

    while (scanf("%s", &str))
    {
        if (str[0] == '*')
            break;
        else if (str[0] == 'H')
            printf("Case %d: Hajj-e-Akbar\n", i);
        else
            printf("Case %d: Hajj-e-Asghar\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

For the input

```
Hajj
Umrah
*
```

When I gave this input at a time, the program provides the expected output by printing

```
Hajj
Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar
Umrah
Case 2: Hajj-e-Asghar
*
```

But after getting `*` as input, the program is waiting for an `Enter`. After hitting `Enter`, the program terminates. But I want my program to terminate, whenever it gets `*` as input, not by pressing `Enter`. Please help me here. But this is not my question. My question is for the same input-

```
Hajj
Umrah
*
```

When I take input by `scanf("%s\n", &str)`. The program does not print the output `Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar` after the first input `Hajj` but it prints the output for first input after taking the second input `Umrah`. Then the program is waiting for an `Enter` for the input `*`.
The output is like this

```
Hajj
Umrah
Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar
*
```

Then I press `Enter`, it prints the output `Case 2: Hajj-e-Asghar` for the second input `Umrah`
and then waits for another input. This the output looks like after pressing `Enter`.

```
Hajj
Umrah
Case 1: Hajj-e-Akbar
*
Case 2: Hajj-e-Asghar
```

I don't understand how `\n` is making a difference in `scanf`.

Thank you.

I'm sorry if I can't explain my question correctly. I am new to programming.

Comment: You should not use `&` operator on arrays. They already decay to pointers. You will not notice as the value is the same, but you are actually providing incorrect type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `\n` in the `scanf` is a bad idea: any whitespace character in the format string causes any sequence of whitespace characters to be discarded from the input stream. If reading from a file, you will not necessary have a problem but if you read from the terminal, `scanf()` will not return until you have typed the next item, and this will create major confusion as you experience, because the program's output will correspond to the previous item, not the one that was just typed... Never add trailing spaces or newlines in a `scanf()` format string.

You should test if `scanf()` returns `1` to avoid an infinite loop when it returns `EOF` at the end of file.

Note also that it is incorrect to pass `&str`: `str` is an array, passing it as `str` will effectively pass a pointer to its first element, which is correct.

Furthermore, you should tell `scanf()` the maximum number of characters that can be stored into the destination array to avoid undefined behavior on overlong input. Since the array is defined with a size of `100`, the format string should be `"%99s"` to leave space for the null terminator.

Finally, you need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the final `*` for 3 combined reasons, each of which would force this behavior:

- the terminal device driver is line buffered by default, so the input is not made available to the program until you type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- the standard input stream (`stdin`) is line buffered by default, so it will read data from the system handle until it gets a newline, and only then does `scanf()` get a chance to see the first character of the entered line.
- `scanf("%s", str)` will keep its input stream until it gets the end of the word, a whitespace character or the end of file, so it does not return when you type just `*`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i = 1;

    while (scanf("%99s", str) == 1 && str[0] != '*') {
        if (str[0] == 'H') {
            printf("Case %d: Hajj-e-Akbar\n", i);
        } else {
            printf("Case %d: Hajj-e-Asghar\n", i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` reads formated input, so when you use `%s\n”, &str` the string will consumed and stored in `str` as will the newline character , which will be present in the buffer when you press enter, the string will be stored and the newline character will be discarded.

Note that the correct usage is `“%s\n”, str`, `str` is already a pointer you shouldn't use `&`.

When you use `“%s”, &str` the newline character will be left in the buffer and will be consumed in the next loop, so `str` will be stored in the first iteration, and `"\n"` will be stored in `str` in the next iteration, only then you will be asked for input again, in the third iteration.

For completion, as stated in the comments bellow, as per the definition of [**`scanf`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> ...any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from the input (determined as if by calling [isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) in a loop). Note that there is no difference between "\n", " ", "\t\t", or other whitespace in the format string.

I would also advise you to limit the size of the string expected by `scanf` to avoid container overflow, something like `%99s` for a 100 charaters container like you have, and also check `scanf` return, in this case, it must be `= 1` for each cycle.

To do what you want, which I gather is to get a character from `stdin` without pressing return you will need a SO specific method, here is a small example for Windows using `<conio.h>` library, and `getch()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1, c;

    while (1)
    {
        if ((c = getch()) == '*')
            return 0;
        else if (c == 'H')
            printf("Case %d: Hajj-e-Akbar\n", i);
        else
            printf("Case %d: Hajj-e-Asghar\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

For Linux one option is to use also [getch()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) from `<ncurses.h>` library, which you [might need to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270381/how-do-i-install-ncurses-header-files).

PS: Don't worry, your question is well built, specially being only the second in the site.

Comment: Actually, I don't know about pointer. That's why I have used `&`. When I used `scanf("%s", str)` and I gave the following input at a time, this may happen.


   `Hajj
    Umrah
    *`

First, it takes the string `Hajj`, and displays its output.Then it takes the second input `Umrah` and displays its output. These two outputs are displayed without hitting any `Enter`, cause it has two new lines after each input. But when the program gets `*` as an input, it's not executed without hitting `Enter`. That's why I have to hit `Enter` at the last input. Is my explanation correct?

Comment: @EhsanulKarimPappu to do what you want there is no portable solution, if you are using Windows you can try `getch()` from `<conio.h>` library or, for linux, `<ncurses.h>` library reads from stdin without enter. The behavior u describe may be due to UB given the wrong type assigment.

Comment: @EhsanulKarimPappu, I edited the answer to provide you with some options I think might do what you need.